# Counting query result on this dataset

Tags: php, mysql, count

with the following query:

```
$result = mysql_query(
"SELECT Stats.champion
FROM Stats, Games
WHERE Stats.game_id = Games.game_id
AND Stats.win = 1
AND Games.game_mode = 'ODIN'");
```

I am returned the following dataset:

```
Ezreal 
Garen 
Pantheon 
Ahri 
Sion 
Rammus 
Nidalee 
Poppy 
Heimerdinger 
Graves 
KogMaw 
Gangplank 
Tristana 
Fizz 
Pantheon 
Pantheon 
Evelynn 
MasterYi 
Tryndamere 
Leona 
Vayne 
Malphite 
Graves 
Shaco 
Nidalee 
Graves 
Heimerdinger 
Gangplank 
JarvanIV 
Akali
```

My goal is to count the result for each name. I know for one, for example "Pantheon", I can do:

```
$result = mysql_query(
"SELECT Stats.champion
FROM Stats, Games
WHERE Stats.game_id = Games.game_id
AND Stats.champion = 'Pantheon'
AND Stats.win = 1
AND Games.game_mode = 'ODIN'");

$pantheonwins = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $pantheonwins;
```

This results with the correct information!

```
Pantheon 
Pantheon 
Pantheon 
3
```

So since this gives me the correct data, is this the most efficient way to get the win count for each individual name, then get a total number of records to computer percents?

Comment: Please go back to your previous questions and select an appropriate answer; by doing this others will be more inclined to assist you.

Comment: @Dennis I only commented on an answer saying it worked for me 11 minutes ago, how could I, according to you 50 minutes ago, select the right answer? lol these things take time to implement! On a lighter note, as I mentioned, an answer has been selected. I am grateful for the help received.

Comment: I was referring to your previous 20 questions, but I now see they have not even been answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your query to this:

```
SELECT
    Stats.champion,
    count(Stats.champion) as myCount
FROM
    Stats, Games
WHERE 
    Stats.game_id = Games.game_id
    AND Stats.win = 1
    AND Games.game_mode = 'ODIN'
GROUP BY
    Stats.champion
```

Now, you should get the count along with the `champion` in the query result.

Comment: Got it working dude! Thanks a lot. If you see my question about calculating percents, I don't need to here. Sorry! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Stats.champion, COUNT(*) as aCount
FROM Stats, Games
WHERE Stats.game_id = Games.game_id
AND Stats.win = 1
AND Games.game_mode = 'ODIN'
GROUP BY Stats.champion
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
SELECT Stats.champion
FROM Stats, Games
    WHERE Stats.game_id = Games.game_id
    AND Stats.champion = 'Pantheon'
    AND Stats.win = 1
    AND Games.game_mode = 'ODIN'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(Stats.champion) as champion
FROM Stats, Games
    WHERE Stats.game_id = Games.game_id
    AND Stats.champion = 'Pantheon'
    AND Stats.win = 1
    AND Games.game_mode = 'ODIN'
```

will return

```
Champion 
=============
Pantheon 
Pantheon 
Pantheon 
3
```

but if you want to have results like this:

```
Champion       |        Result
==============================
Pantheon       |            3
```

then you should used this:

```
SELECT STATS.champion as Champion, COUNT(GAMES.game_id) as `Result`
FROM Stats INNER JOIN Games ON  Stats.game_id = Games.game_id
WHERE Stats.win = 1 AND Games.game_mode = 'ODIN'
GROUP BY Champion
```